# Populate a list inside a linq select statement using the query's index

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a list (assume it has values):

```
var IdNumber = new List<string>();
```

and I have a linq:

```
var output = list.Select(y => new {
Id = IdNumber[index],
Name = y.Name,
}).ToList();
```

Is there an index that can be used to populate 'IdNumber' in Id? If it is impossible, is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Select can give an index.

```
var output = list.Select((y,index) => new {
Id = IdNumber[index],
Name = y.Name,
}).ToList();
```

Basic demo:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var list = new[]{"abc","abc","abc"};

    foreach (var item in list.Select((x,i)=>x[i]))
        Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

output

```
a
b
c
```

[Try it online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PBbU7L)

Select implementation:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int, TResult> selector) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    if (selector == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("selector");
    return SelectIterator<TSource, TResult>(source, selector);
}

static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectIterator<TSource, TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int, TResult> selector) {
   int index = -1;
       foreach (TSource element in source) {
          checked { index++; }
          yield return selector(element, index);
    }
}
```

[source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,38)

Answer (score 0):

select in linq has its built-in index. You just have to specify a second argument in the code.

Replace the beginning of your code with

```
var output = list.Select((y, index) => new {
...
}).ToList();
```